# Order a Multiline Textboxes by Character Number

Tags: vb.net

I want to order a Multiline by character, this code should do this, unfortunately it does not.

```
Dim strs = New String() {TxtListScanTxt.Text}
Dim sorted = strs.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Length).ThenBy(Function(x) x).ToArray()
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = sorted
```

Output

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,9
1,2,4,8
1,2,5,7
3,12
4,5,6
7,8
15
```

Output: Expected:

```
15
7,8
3,12
4,5,6
1,2,5,7
1,2,4,8
1,2,3,9
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: `.Text` is not an array of strings.

Comment: Also, edit your question to input the value of `TxtListScanTxt.Text`

Comment: Your output shouldn't even be that.  `Dim strs() As String = TxtListScanTxt.Lines`.  Then use OrderByDescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easy if you didn't want to sort lists of numbers individually. Also, since you are sorting the individual lists (of the same count) by numeric items, you can't use a string sort. What I mean is

> 9,5
>   10,6

How do you sort that? You would compare `9` with `1`, in `9` and `10`, respectively, if doing an alphabetical sort, and `9` would be greater than `10`. I think you should parse each individual element as an integer beforehand.

So my code here is complex, and involves grouping the lines by item count first, then ordering the lines within their groups. I suppose this could be put into one line but this is more readable (though, still not very...)

```vb
Dim lines = TxtListScanTxt.Lines.Select(Function(l) l.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s)))
Dim groups = lines.GroupBy(Function(l) l.Count()).OrderBy(Function(g) g.Key)
Dim sortedGroups = groups.Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(gi) gi.Reverse().Select(Function(i, v) v * 10 ^ i).Sum())).SelectMany(Function(g) g)
Dim result = sortedGroups.Select(Function(g) String.Join(",", g))
TxtListScanTxt.Lines = result.ToArray()
```

Recursion could be used to do sort each sub group by their numbers, but we could also take a sum, and I'm trying to do this with LINQ. The magic in `Function(i, v) v * 10 ^ i).Sum()` is that we will sort by creating a number out of your list by multiplying each successive item by 10 to a higher order of magnitude then summing.

> 1,2,3,9 = 1000 * 1 + 100 * 2 + 10 * 3 + 9 = 1239
>   1,2,4,8 = 1000 * 1 + 100 * 2 + 10 * 4 + 8 = 1248

and 1248 should come before 1239 (so order by descending for these sub groups)

You could say concatenate the characters into an integer but once you get into double digits, that breaks down. This method handles that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the text in multiple lines before try to order the lines:

The `TextBox` has a `Lines` property that already gives an `Array` containing each line of the `Text`.

```
Dim Lines() As String = TxtListScanTxt.Lines   ' System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\myfile.txt")  ' TxtListScanTxt.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)  ' You can use this if you want to split the text from a string
Dim SortedLines = Lines.OrderBy(Function(Line) Line.Length).ToArray()

TxtListScanTxt.Lines = SortedLines
```

Initial screen:
[image: Initial Screenshot]

Result after sort:
[image: After sorting]

Comment: Check the order of the 4-item items.

Comment: Your method is very interesting. (The 4-item items are not ordered,3º is 5,4,3 and 4º is 7,8,9.) I did a simple answer, he said he only wanted to order by character number, ie. line length, (but I think that he probably will need a code that takes in account the line lenght and also the individual numbers separated by comma. )

Comment: I gathered that, since his list was ordered that way

Comment: If we have {`8,7`, `9,6`, `10,5`}, these alphabetically sort like {`10,5`, `8,7`, `9,6`} because 1 is compared with 8 and 9. That resulting order seems arbitrary, unless OP wanted alphabetical order, in which case that's fine. But numerically it's wrong! But in either case you need to order descending to match OP's desired list.